# Fetch user role from oauth app in authentication response

Tags: spring, spring-security, okta

We are using Okta as a OAuth login provider.
What we wish to achieve is to fetch user role information in the authentication response itself. We are using spring security.

Currently we get following details in org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.OidcUser object

[image]

[Edit]
Adding content of authorities

[image]

This does not include user role information. Is there a way to get the user role information in the authentication response itself?

Comment: What do you mean by *This does not include user role information.* You have 4 roles, see `authorities`.

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev We request for these scopes - "openid", "email", "profile"

Comment: @dur In the authoriites, I do get - ROLE_USER authority. However, this user is a super admin user and the ROLE_USER authority does not mention that.

Comment: do you mean super admin user should be getting different role? did you map the user with the correct role ?

Comment: @Aleson The screenshots attached are for a User who is assigned Super Admin Role in Okta. In the authorities, I did not get any property which indicates that this is a Super Admin User. 

Essentially, I need the role assigned to the user, let it be Super Admin or Developer or something else.

Comment: can you show us the user data in the Okta dashboard? are you sure you already map the required role to the user?

Comment: Try to request `groups` scope as well, to see if spring can process the roles of a user returned by okta

Comment: You can add a `groups` claim to the ID and/or access token. https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/customize-tokens-groups-claim/